# website only renders on half page on mobile devices using NextJS and Tailwind

Tags: next.js, responsive-design, tailwind-css, portfolio

Perhaps a bit foolishly, I have chosen to do my portfolio site with two technologies that I have never worked with before - Tailwind and NextJS.

while developing the portfolio, I have opened it via my mobile browser and was surprised to see that the components are rendering on half screen only. This does not happen when I refit the device width manually in the browser on the desktop.

In index.js I have the following meta tag, which I thought could fix the issue

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Would anyone have idea why that happens?

My code is deployed to [github](https://github.com/rodages/portfolio)

[image: Mobile picture of the portfolio]

Many thanks,
Zan

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: thanks @Rob. Unfortunately I did not know if the problem was originating because of NextJs, or TailwindCSS , neither I was able to determine which component causes the bug. Luckily for me, Nicolae has spotted that some components had picture width set to fixed px causing this bug. Thanks for your time checking out though and for sharing the correct practices.

Comment: Note that your question and the answer will be closed and deleted eventually for the reason stated.

Answer (score 1):

Your parent images have a fixed width, try to remove it, or add max-width.

[image]

Comment: Many Thanks! how silly of me was it not to check the other components to see if something else takes the whole width!

However, for some reason - if I set maxWidth - the component is not being displayed anymore.

Comment: Try to remove style={{  width: '1200px', height: '600px'}} className='relative' (https://github.com/rodages/portfolio/blob/main/components/Projects.js#L18)

Comment: when I done so - the pictures get rendered at the very top of the page. 

style={{ width: '100%', height: '600px'}} className='relative'

this worked for me to tackle the current issue. Many thanks once again!